# Javascript Angular 4 CLI SCSS issue after added css

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have just created a new angular project using the Angular CLI for Angualr 4.

I generated it with SCSS so:

ng new myproject --style=sass

It all compiles well until I add some css.

For example I added this to app.component.scss

```
.test {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

And as soon as I save I get this error:

Failed to compile.

```
./src/app/app.component.sass
Module build failed: 
.test {
      ^
      Invalid CSS after ".test {": expected "}", was "{"
      in C:\Users\me\Documents\myproject\src\app\app.component.sass (line 1, column 8)
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 18:17-48
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: change this to `./src/app/app.component.scss` instead of `./src/app/app.component.sass`

Comment: you can also do opposite `ng new myproject --style=scss` by defining scss not sass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two things: SASS and SCSS.

SASS syntax:

```
.test
    padding: 20px
```

SCSS syntax:

```
.test {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Try renaming the file to `app.component.scss` and it should work.

To use SCSS as default with your angular CLI project, update it in your `.angular-cli.json` file (in your project root):

```
{
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "scss",
    }
}
```

Or you can use `ng set defaults.styleExt scss`.

Comment: Oh, I might have installed sass when I wanted to install scss :(  If there a way of changing cli to generate scss instead of sass or do I need to create a new project again?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer with that a few minutes ago, just edit the `.angular-cli.json` file, I think that should be enought.

Comment: No need to worry about installing new engine for scss, as its the same as for sass (sass is just a different syntax for it).